# //lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: nasm, ld, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to run a file that I wrote in September 2008 and I used the Ubuntu version of that year and it worked well. Now I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 with NASM version 2.10.09.

Here's the file's source code https://gist.github.com/vcrobe/2494f0f54c03f8fb0a8d

I've compiled the code with NASM successfully with this command:

```
nasm -f elf foo.asm
```

but when I try to link the object file with this command:

```
ld -s -o foo foo.o -lelf -I/lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

I get the following error:

```
ld: foo.o: undefined reference to symbol 'printf@@GLIBC_2.0'
//lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line.
```

Can somebody tell me what do I've to do to solve the problem?

What have changed since then because it used to work in 2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the GNU C library like this.  Ordinarily the C compiler will link in 3 other files: `crti.o` (where `_start` is supposed to be defined), `crt0.o` (or `crt1.o`), and `crtn.o`.  These files contain the initialization, startup, and teardown procedures that the GNU C library depends on for its methods and symbols to even be *resolved*.

If you intend to make use of the C library's `printf` function (or any other libc function for that matter) then you need to do it from within the method `main`.

So first you have to change your `_start` symbol to `main`.  Then you have change your linker command to one of two options.  The easy one is

```
gcc -s -o foo foo.o -lelf
```

The harder one is

```
ld -s -o foo /lib/i386-linux-gnu/crti.o /lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o foo.o \
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/crtn.o -I/lib/ld-linux.so.2 -lc
```

**Note**: the order in which you specify the object files to link is very important.  The order *must* be `crti.o` then `crt{0,1}.o` then you link in your own object files and only after all of that do you link in `crtn.o`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. When I try the second option ld... I get the following errors "ld: cannot find /lib/i386-linux-gnu/crti.o: No such file or directory" and the same for crt1.o and crtn.o. How can I fix this? I really need to link the object file in this way.

Comment: @vcRobe If they aren't there then use `locate` to track them down.  They might be in the `/usr/lib/` directory instead of the `/lib` directory.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to add the linker option to link with the C library.  It's there now.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot man. You're right I used locate and the crt files are located at /usr/lib and yes if I don't use -lc it doesn't link. Also I had to rename _start with "main" as you suggested. Thanks again.

One question that comes to my mind now is why it worked in 2008? Because I didn't change the code since then?

Comment: @vcRobe Probably because just after 2008 was when the GNU C library started needing the initialization and finalization routines to be linked.  But I'm no expert.